# Print only distinct elements from a string, using python

Tags: string

Print the all the words that are left in the string 's' so that the words in the output sentence have distinct words compared to their adjacent words.using python
Sample Input :
I am john cena cena john
Sample Output :
I am

a=list(map(str,input().split()))
print(a)
b=[]
for j in range(2):
for i in range(0,len(a)-2):
if a[i]==a[i+1]:
a.pop(i)
a.pop(i+1)
else:
b.append(a[i])

print(*b)

input:I am john cena cena john
outout:i m john i m

Comment: Does the order of the output matter?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: 1) Order matters,

Comment: 2) question is => like input = i am john cena cena  john , output= i  am ,                            only Similar adjacent strings need to be removed.                                                               if input be like = we love we love ,output = we love we love  ,                            because here adjacent strings are not similar